# Bridge between two WebSocket STOMP servers

Tags: websocket, activemq-classic, stomp

We have an ActiveMQ server and our own API with WebSocket/STOMP service endpoint.

Is there a way to configure ActiveMQ to connect and subscribe to a topic in our API and then publish the messages in ActiveMQ?

If not, are there any other WebSocket/STOMP bridge components which could be used to achieve the same thing (subscribe to a topic in our API and post messages to a topic in ActiveMQ)?

The motivation of all this is... complicated.

Comment: I did. I haven't been able to connect to a WebSocket with ActiveMQ's built-in Camel. Someone told me in Camel's Zulip discussion that the reason might be that ActiveMQ's built-in Camel is quite old. So I investigated a possibility to build a resent version of standalone Camel, but that seemed like it would take me some time. So now I've just written a simple Python bridge. I'd like to learn more about Camel later, when I have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ActiveMQ natively supports Camel routes](https://activemq.apache.org/broker-camel-component). You could potentially use Camel's [STOMP component](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.4.x/stomp-component.html) to subscribe to your own STOMP endpoint and then send those messages to a local destination.